# JavascriptExecutor in Squash TM with Selenium WebDriver won't work

Tags: java, javascript, selenium-webdriver

For testing purposes, I have to execute simple JavaScript queries using the Selenium's WebDriver on a Squash TM server.

This is how my Java code looks like :

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String test = (String) js.executeScript("return 'test';");
System.out.println(test);
```

This code works fine on my computer when executed with Squash TA Eclipse IDE, but it doesn't work on another computer with the same IDE.

Finally, it won't work as an automation test on Squash TM server. The test will just fail and surrounding the code with `try... catch` doesn't print anything.

Is there some other way to execute some JavaScript with Squash TM Server ? Or a fix to make JavascriptExecutor work ?

Comment: Did you mean "Squash TA server" ? Don't you have any kind of error log ?